# Jenkins download source code from CA Harvest with harvest.sig

Tags: jenkins, harvest-scm

I find this file harvest.sig in the job workspace when downloading source code from CA SCM in Jenkins (using CA Harvest Win Broker). Why and how to resolve this?

Comment: What is the problem with that file?

Comment: @Robert, that file is not part of the actual application source code.

Comment: Check any option available to disable it. There is an option in harvest java API to disable it setSignatureOption(boolean).